# Sql: Aggregation First() After Order by and Group by

Tags: sql

```
id | name | value | time |
--------------------------
1  | A | 1 | 1 | 
2  | B | 2 | 2 | 
3  | C | 2 | 3 | 
4  | A | 3 | 3 | 
5  | A | 4 | 2 |
```

and I expected the result as below:

```
name | value |
--------------
 A | 3 | 
 B | 2 | 
 C | 2 |
```

The results are to show name and value which are lastest time and not duplicate with name.
And I try to query:

```
SELECT name,First(value)
FROM
(SELECT name,value,time
FROM test
ORDER BY time DESC
)
GROUP BY name;
```

But I got this result:

```
name | value |
--------------
 A | 1 | 
 B | 2 | 
 C | 2 |
```

I don't understand why A value isn't 3 because from subselect I got A values are 3,4,1 respectively.

Comment: What databese system you're using?

Comment: Now I test on Access. But don't don't worry about it. I will test on other system also.
But I suspect in my code very much, why it doesn't work.
I have just used simple SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da25e/3)**

```
SELECT t.name,
       (SELECT t1.value
        FROM test t1
        WHERE t1.name = t.name
        ORDER BY t1.time DESC
        LIMIT 1) AS value 
FROM test t
GROUP BY t.name
```

Result:

```
| NAME | VALUE |
----------------
|    A |     3 |
|    B |     2 |
|    C |     2 |
```

Comment: `First()` function is very rare, mysql don't have such a function. Probably Access let you do it, because he have VBA functions...

Answer (score 0):

also you can use partitionby

```
;with cte as (
  select id, row_number() over (order by time desc) rn
  from test
)
select * from test
join cte on test.id = cte.id and rn = 1
```

just choose the one which is faster